# How to pass in correlation id into IHttpProvider?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to pass correlation Id into the IHttpProvider to let them log it for debugging purpose. How should I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a great solution for you to provide your own correlation Id today, however it something that we are working on.  Requests that are made to Graph will get assigned a request id and you should be able to see that in the response headers.  You could add your own using header using .Request(options).